# Create consecutive sublists of given length from a list in LISP

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, sublist

I have a list `(1 2 3 4 5 6)` and I would like to create all possible lists of 4 atoms, for example. The result would be `((1 2 3 4)(2 3 4 5)(3 4 5 6))`.

Is this possible in Lisp? Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: see `alexandria:rotate` or `map-combinations` or `map-permutations`? https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Sequences

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun slide (list n)
  (loop for head on list
        for tail = (nthcdr n list) then (cdr tail)
        collect (ldiff head tail)
        while tail))
```

Tests:

```
[1]> (slide nil 0) 
NIL
[2]> (slide nil 1)
NIL
[3]> (slide nil 2)
NIL
[4]> (slide '(1) 0)
(NIL)
[5]> (slide '(1) 1)
((1))
[6]> (slide '(1) 2)
((1))
[7]> (slide '(1) 3)
((1))
[8]> (slide '(1 2 3) 0)
(NIL NIL NIL)
[9]> (slide '(1 2 3) 1)
((1) (2) (3))
[10]> (slide '(1 2 3) 2)
((1 2) (2 3))
[11]> (slide '(1 2 3) 3)
((1 2 3))
[12]> (slide '(1 2 3) 4)
((1 2 3))
[13]> (slide '(1 2 3) 5)
((1 2 3))
[14]> (slide '(1 2 3 4 5) 3)
((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5))
[15]> (slide '(1 2 3 4 5) 4)
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5))
[16]> (slide '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
((1 2 3 4 5))
[17]> (slide '(1 2 3 4 5) 6)
```

The test cases where `n` exceeds the length of the list, or is zero, are out of spec; including those just to show the actual behavior. A value of -1 will violate the contract of `nthcdr`, and should signal an error consequently, except if compiled for low safety.

How it works:

- the `on` in `for head on list` iterates over the `cons` cell backbone of the list rather than the items. The `head` loop variable is set to `list` on the first iteration. Then on the second iteration it goes to `(cdr head)`. This will terminate when `nil` is hit.
- in parallel with this iteration, we have `for tail = (nthcdr n list) then (cdr tail)`.  This is very similar to `for tail on (nthcdr n list)`. The `tail` variable is initialized to `n` cells down the list, and then marches by `cdr`.  The reason we don't use the `for var on list` clause is is that we don't want to terminate when the loop variable hits `nil`. When `tail` becomes `nil`, we want to include that `nil` value in the iteration, and so we open-code the desired iteration using the `for var = initial-val then step-val` clause of `loop`.
- thus we have `head` and `tail` pointers marching through the list at an offset from each other, like in this diagram,showing the list `(1 2 3 4)` and the initial state of `head` and `tail` with `n` being 2:

  ```
    [ 1 | * ] <--- head
          |
          v
        [ 2 | * ]
              |
              v
            [ 3  | * ] <---  tail
                   |
                   v
                 [ 4 | NIL ]
  ```

  so here, on the first iteration, we will calculate `(ldiff head tail)`. What that returns is a copy of the prefix of the `head` list, without the `tail` portion. `ldiff` marches down the `head` list, copying the items into a new list, and stops copying when it encounters the `tail` pointer.   If you understand `git`, then `(ldiff head tail)` is something like like `git cherry-pick tail..head`. Items from `head` are cherry picked into the returned list until `tail`, which is not cherry picked. In this example, `(ldiff head tail)` yields `(1 2)`. `tail` points at the `(3 4)`, and that is excluded.
- On each iteration, `head` and `tail` both march down the list by one cell, in parallel, so the `ldiff` will keep calculating a different `n`-sized slice of the list. Next time we will collect `(2 3)`.
- On the last iteration, `tail` becomes `nil`. In this case, `(ldiff head tail)` then just behaves like `(copy-list head)`: it keeps copying items into a new list, until it encounters `tail`. Since that is `nil`, that conditions happens when it hits the end of the list, at which point it has copied all of it.
- Termination is ensured by `while tail`. This clause is put at the bottom so that we have a bottom test: we want to include the iteration when `tail` is `nil`, but then stop.

On a different note, here is a solution in the TXR Lisp language which shows how this problem can be solved with pattern matching. This an easily be transcribed to work with other Lisp dialects and their available pattern matching libraries, like Trivia for Common Lisp.

```
1> (append-each ((tail (conses '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))))
      (if-match (@a @b @c @d . @nil) tail
         ^((,a ,b ,c ,d))))
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6) (4 5 6 7))
```

Only problem is, we hard-coded the parameter n, since is it is represented by the length of the pattern, which is a piece of syntax in the code.

There are situations where I would prefer this solution, particularly if the requirements change in certain ways. For instance, suppose we needed to collect only those quadruplets which satisfy some arithmetic property. It would be handy to be able to refer to the tuple elements by the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` variable names.

We can introduce constraints right in the pattern itself. For instance: collect only tuples that start with 1:

```
5> (append-each ((tail (conses '(1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4))))
      (if-match (1 @b @c @d . @nil) tail
        ^((1 ,b ,c ,d))))
((1 2 1 2) (1 2 3 1) (1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4))
```

Another way, which keeps the variable `a`:

```
7> (append-each ((tail (conses '(1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4))))
      (if-match (@(eql 1 @a) @b @c @d . @nil) tail
        ^((,a ,b ,c ,d))))
((1 2 1 2) (1 2 3 1) (1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4))
```

Or tuples ending in an odd number:

```
8> (append-each ((tail (conses '(1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4))))
      (if-match (@a @b @c @(oddp @d) . @nil) tail
        ^((,a ,b ,c ,d))))
((2 1 2 3) (1 2 3 1) (3 1 2 3) (2 3 4 5) (4 5 6 1) (6 1 2 3))
```

Or use guard expressions (via the `require` operator in this pattern matcher) to collect only tuples whose last two elements add to five:

```
9> (append-each ((tail (conses '(1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4))))
      (if-match @(require (@a @b @c @d . @nil)
                          (= 5 (+ c d)))
                tail
        ^((,a ,b ,c ,d))))
((2 1 2 3) (3 1 2 3) (6 1 2 3))
```

Comment: took care of those edge cases. :) (never knew about `ldiff` before...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
[7]> (mapcar #'list '(1 2 3 4 5 6) '(2 3 4 5 6) '(3 4 5 6) '(4 5 6))
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6))
```

That's too specific a code. A more general way to write the same thing is

```
[9]> (apply #'mapcar (cons #'list 
       '((1 2 3 4 5 6) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6) (4 5 6)) ))
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6))
```

Now this is more readily generalizable. It suggests we need to implement a function that will work like this:

```
(foo 4 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=>
((1 2 3 4 5 6) (2 3 4 5 6) (3 4 5 6) (4 5 6))
```

Then our solution would be achievable as

```
(defun sublists (n lst)
  (apply #'mapcar (cons #'list
     (foo n lst))))
```

What's left is to implement this `foo`. It needs to iterate `n` times (or is it `n-1`?), taking the `rest` each time:

```
[10]> (rest '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(2 3 4 5 6)
[11]> (rest *)
(3 4 5 6)
[12]> (rest *)
(4 5 6)
[13]> (rest *)
(5 6)
[14]> (rest *)
(6)
[15]> (rest *)
NIL
[16]> (rest *)
NIL
```

Try implementing it, also taking care of all the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defun partition (n list &key step)
  "Collects a list of N items from the LIST, moving STEP times forward in each iteration"
  (labels ((take (m list)
             (when (<= m (length list))
               (loop for i from 0 to (decf m)
                     collect (nth i list)))))
    (unless step
      (setf step n))
    (assert (> step 0))
    (let ((p (take n list)))
      (when (= n (length p))
        (cons p (partition n (nthcdr step list) :step step))))))

;;; Your example

CL-USER> (partition 4 '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :step 1)
((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6))
```

Some more examples:

```lisp
CL-USER> (partition 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
CL-USER> (partition 2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :step 1)
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6))
CL-USER> (partition 2 '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :step 2)
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
CL-USER> (partition 1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :step 2)
((1) (3) (5))
```

Comment: Don't know why this was voted negatively. It solves the problem and is a more generic solution. Helped me to solve another problem. Thanks.

Comment: probably because there is no explanation, just code and examples. I thought there was no need to explain it further. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

another one, combining loops and mapcar application:

```
(defun slide (n data)
  (when (>= (length data) n)
    (loop repeat n
          for x on data
          collect x into res
          finally (return (apply #'mapcar #'list res)))))

CL-USER> (slide 4 (list 1 2 3))
;;=> NIL

CL-USER> (slide 4 (list 1 2 3 4))
;;=> ((1 2 3 4))

CL-USER> (slide 4 (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
;;=> ((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6) (4 5 6 7) (5 6 7 8))
```